# Ruby Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby. I have problems with the following code on my windows environment:

```
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'

    url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/spectre_2015"
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    print page
```

[ruby_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcMjy.png)

and get this error:

PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\crawler> ruby crawl.rb
crawl.rb:5:in `initialize': Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/spectre_2015 (Errno::EINVAL) from crawl.rb:5:in` open'
from crawl.rb:5:in `'
PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\crawler>

1. downloaded / installed ruby + visual studio code
2. created folder crawler + file crawl.rb
3. gem install nokogiri + gem install open-uri
4. run code

I am thankful for every help....

Comment: It would be helpful if you paste your code here instead of a link to an image.

Comment: What version of Ruby and 'nokogiri', and 'open-uri' gems do you use?

Comment: My fault... i added the code....

Comment: -ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: # Nokogiri (1.11.7)

Comment: _open-uri_ used to redefine `Kernel#open`, so you could open URLs just via `open`. However, this behavior was deprecated in Ruby 2.7 and the patching was removed in Ruby 3. You now have to use `URI.open` when opening URLs.

Comment: @Stefan: the documentation for open-uri tells us to use `URI.open` in [2.4.0](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) already

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I assume that the OP is following an older Nokogiri / open-uri tutorial and wanted to shed some light on that `open` call.

Comment: @Stefan: ah, so you're saying the patching was still in place until recently? Even though they stopped advertising it long ago?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev they only changed the docs in Ruby 2.4, the deprecation warning was added in Ruby 2.7. And regardless of that change, there are many tutorials out there from pre-2.4 times where `open` was still the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `:open` you call belongs to `Kernel` class:

```rb
> method :open
=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#open(*)>
```

I believe you want to call `URI.open` because you require `open-uri` gems.

```rb
page Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation of [`Kernel#open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-open), if your path argument does not start with a `|` character, it is treated as a file [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## open(path [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) → io or nil
>
> ## open(path [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|io| block } → obj
>
> Creates an IO object connected to the given stream, file, or subprocess.
>
> If `path` does not start with a pipe character (|), **treat it as the name of a file to open** using the specified mode (defaulting to “r”).

So, you are telling Ruby to open a subdirectory of the current directory named `https:`, and inside that subdirectory open a subdirectory named `www.rottentomatoes.com`, and inside that subdirectory open a subdirectory named `m`, and inside that subdirectory open a file named `spectre_2015`. And what Ruby is telling you, is that it cannot find that file.

If what you are trying to do is to download the document to which that URI resolves, then you can use the [`open-uri`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) library that is part of the Ruby standard library. The `open-uri` library provides a method called [`URI::open`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-open), which lets you treat a URI like an [`IO` stream](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html):

```ruby
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/spectre_2015'
page = Nokogiri.HTML(URI.open(url))

print page
```